# jQuery show dynamic content on a dialog

Tags: jquery, dynamic, dialog, popup

I have this dialog:

```
function OpenCopyDialog() {

var $link = $(this); //keep track of the element that was clicked

$("#confirmCopyBox").html("</br><h2>Your are about to copy application number: <span>P</span>@application.Id</h2> </br> <h1> Do you want to continue?</h1>");

$("#confirmCopyBox").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    title: "Copy Confirmation",
    height: 250,
    width: 400,
    buttons: {
        "Yes": function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            callback(true, $link); //pass the reference to the element
        },
        "No": function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            callback(false);
        }
    }
});
event.preventDefault();
```

}

And a table with these elements:

```
<tr>
                        <td><a href="@APPP.GetURL("applicationsFormPageId")?ApplicationId=@application.Id"><span>P</span>@application.Id</a></td>
                        <td>@application.Street</td>
                        <td>13-Jun-2014</td>
                        <td>Incomplete</td>
                        <td>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "YourApplications", new {Id = application.Id }, new { @class = "confirmDelete" })</td>
                        <td>@Html.ActionLink("Copy", "Copy", "YourApplications", new { Id = application.Id }, new { @class = "confirmCopy" })</td>
                        <td><a href="#">download</a></td>
                    </tr>
```

The idea is to show in the jQuery popup the dynamic element: `<span>P</span>@application.Id`.

So each time that the user tries to copy or delete, he has a confirmation popup that asks him if he really want to delete or copy THAT ELEMENT.

If you need extra info please tell me but don't downvote me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did:

```
var $link = $(this); //keep track of the element that was clicked

var myAppHref = $link.attr('href');
var arrayString = myAppHref.split('/');
var myAppIDclean = arrayString[arrayString.length-1];

$("#confirmDeleteBox").html("</br><h2>You are about to Delete application number: <span>P</span>" + myAppIDclean + "</h2> </br> <h1> Do you want to continue?</h1>");
```

It worked fine.